# Not possible to instantiate it as an implementation of DataModel

Tags: castle-windsor

I just configured Castle-Windsor and am receiving this message:

Type DataModel.IDepartmentRepository is abstract. As such, it is not possible to instansiate it as implementation of DataModel.IDepartmentRepository service.

My Interface looks like this:

```
namespace DataModel  
{  
    public interface IDepartmentRepository  
    {  
        IQueryable<Department> GetAllDepartments();  
        Department GetDepartment(int id);  
        void Add(Department department);  
        void Delete(Department department);  
        void Save();  
    }  
}
```

My Department class is set up as a Partial Class to a class generated by LINQ TO SQL in my dbml file.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the exception is pretty clear.

you need to tell Windsor what type you want to provide the implementation for your `IDepartmentRepository`

Comment: I have this in my Web.Config and getting same results:

  <castle>  
    <components>  
      <component id="DepartmentRepository"  
      service="DataModel.IDepartmentRepository,DataModel"  
      type="DataModel.IDepartmentRepository,DataModel"  
      lifestyle="PerWebRequest">  
      </component>  
    </components>  
  </castle>  

I have IDepartmentRepository is in a separate class library from the MVC Project.  I have IDepartmentRepository in a class library named DataModel. My MVC project is in a Project name MVC.  Does my Web.Config look okay?

Comment: I posed a dumb question, sorry.  Just realized in my config that my TYPE was pointing to IDepartmentRepository and not my type: DepartmentRepository.